# How can I add an empty line (no selection) to my combo box?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Sometimes I need to add an empty row to the NSComboBox to allow an empty selection.

However, since I bind the content values to all instances of a specific core data entity, there are no empty lines.

How can I add an empty line (no selection) instead ?

Thanks

Comment: Anybody with at least a tip ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than binding directly to your entity, bind to a custom property of your controller.

You can then implement setter and getter methods for that property in your controller that do the right thing in terms of displaying the blank item and handling the situation where the blank item is selected.

Comment: I see, but how do I handle the white item ? I mean, should I use NSNull? Or an empty NSManagedObject to delete afterwards ? Consider all the other items are NSManagedObjects

Comment: I think NSNull would work. If you don't like how it displays, bind your array of Null+objects to the Content Values binding instead, and separately bind the Content binding to a property that returns a list of strings.